# Streaming blob content via an Azure Function - the HttpResponseMessage object gets serialised instead of the content

Tags: c#, download, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob

I'm trying to stream content from blob storage to the browser, via an Azure Function. My hope is to stream the content through to the client rather than buffering the entire blob content in memory.

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = route)] HttpRequestData req)
{
    var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(CONNECTION_STRING);
    var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);
    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(BLOB_NAME);
    var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(stream) };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = blob.Name };

    return response;
}
```

But each time I call the function I get a textual response like so:

```
{
  "version": "1.1",
  "content": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": [
          "application/octet-stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Disposition",
        "value": [
          "attachment; filename=\"BLOB_NAME\""
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode": "OK",
  "reasonPhrase": "OK",
  "headers": [],
  "trailingHeaders": [],
  "requestMessage": null,
  "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

As you can see, this looks like the `HttpResponseMessage` object has been serialised and transmitted instead of the content.

What's going wrong? Why is the blob content itself not being transmitted?

Comment: Why don't you `return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");` You're returning an http response message. that's exactly what it should return.

Comment: I haven't used `FileStreamResult` because it's in the `Mvc` namespace, and I'm not building a MVC website. Is it safe/suggested/recommended for use in an Azure Function?

Answer (score 0):

> Streaming blob content via an Azure Function - the HttpResponseMessage object gets serialised instead of the content

I have created azure function with http trigger in dotnet.

I have created azure blob storage and uploaded one blob into container. check below:

[image]

By using below code, I was able to retrieve the content inside the blob in my local environment.

**Function code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

                string name = req.Query["name"];

                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
                name = name ?? data?.name;

                string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                    ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                    : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

                string storageConnectionString = "your-azure storage conn-string";
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("your-container-name");

                List<string> blobNames = new List<string>();
                List<string> blobContents = new List<string>();

                BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);
                foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
                {
                    if (item is CloudBlob blob)
                    {
                        blobNames.Add(blob.Name);

                        // Log additional blob details to the console
                        log.LogInformation($"Blob Name: {blob.Name}");
                        log.LogInformation($"Blob Uri: {blob.Uri}");
                        log.LogInformation($"Blob Properties: LastModified={blob.Properties.LastModified}, ContentType={blob.Properties.ContentType}");

                        // Read the content of the blob
                        using (Stream blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(blobStream))
                        {
                            string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                            blobContents.Add(content);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Log the blob names to the console
                log.LogInformation($"Blob Names in Container: {string.Join(", ", blobNames)}");

                // You can now use blobContents to display the content in the response or further process it as needed.
                string result = $"Blob Names in Container: {string.Join(", ", blobNames)}\nBlob Contents: {string.Join("\n\n", blobContents)}";

                // Include blob retrieval results in the response
                responseMessage += $"\n\nBlob Details: {result}";

                return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details, but I think you've misunderstood - I have no problem uploading a blob and retrieving its details; What I'm trying to do is to download the blob _contents_.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve blob content which is present in portal?

Comment: Well, localhost at this point in time; eventually, yes, from a storage container in an Azure data centre.

Comment: @awj  I have updated the solution. Check once.

Comment: Again, I don't think you've read the OP. I stated the intention is _"to stream the content through to the client rather than buffering the entire blob content in memory"_. What your code does is load the entire blob content into memory before returning in a single response. I appreciate the effort you've spent but I'm tring to rewrite an existing block of code which currently does pretty much what your answer is suggesting.